# Cloning a Linked List not printing correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to define a function called clone which clones the linked list
Here is the LinkedList class with the clone function defined

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, d, n):
    self.data = d
    self.next = n




class LinkedList:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.length = 0

def __str__(self):
    if self.head == None: 
        return "empty"
    st = "-"
    ptr = self.head
    while ptr != None:
        st += "-> "+str(ptr.data)+" "
        ptr = ptr.next
    return st+"None"
    
def search(self, d):
    i = 0
    ptr = self.head
    while ptr != None:
        if ptr.data == d:
            return i
        ptr = ptr.next
        i += 1
    return -1  

def append(self, d):
    if self.head == None:      
        self.head = Node(d,None) 
    else:
        ptr = self.head
        while ptr.next != None:
            ptr = ptr.next
        ptr.next = Node(d,None)
    self.length += 1
def appendEverything(self, A):
   for i in range(len(A)):
        self.append(A[i])
def insert(self, i, d):
    if self.head == None or i == 0:
        self.head = Node(d,self.head)
    else:
        ptr = self.head
        while i>1 and ptr.next != None:
            ptr = ptr.next
            i -= 1
        ptr.next = Node(d,ptr.next)
    self.length += 1

def remove(self, i): # removes i-th element and returns it
    if self.head == None:
        return None
    if i == 0:
        val = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.length -= 1
        return val
    ptr = self.head
    while ptr.next != None:
        if i == 1:
            val = ptr.next.data
            ptr.next = ptr.next.next
            self.length -= 1
            return val                
        ptr = ptr.next
        i -= 1
        
def removeVal(self, d):
    if self.head == None:
        return -1
    if self.head.data == d:
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.length -= 1
        return 0
    else:
        i = 0
        ptr = self.head 
        while ptr.next != None:
            if ptr.next.data == d:
                ptr.next = ptr.next.next
                self.length -= 1
                return i+1
            ptr = ptr.next
            i += 1
    return -1

def sublist(self, i):
    ptr = self.head
    ls = LinkedList()
    ls.length = self.length
    while ptr != None and i>0:
        ptr = ptr.next
        i -= 1
        ls.length -= 1
    ls.head = ptr
    return ls

def get(self, i):
    ptr = self.head
    while i > 0:
        ptr = ptr.next
        i -= 1
    return ptr.data

def set(self, i, d):
    ptr = self.head
    while i > 0:
        ptr = ptr.next
        i -= 1
    ptr.data = d
def clone(self):
    i=0
    ls=LinkedList()
    ptr=self.head
    if ptr==None:
        return ls
    while ptr!=None:
      ls.insert(i,ptr.data)
      ptr=ptr.next
      i+=1
    return ls
```

However I carried out three tests and the the third test comes out incorrect and by the looks of it it’s removing an element

```
list1=LinkedList()
list2=list1.clone()
print(list1, "", list2) #it prints out empty, empty that’s fine 
print("T2")
list1.appendEverything([1,2,3,4])
print(list1, "", list2)# prints ->1->2->3->None and the same for list 2 
print("T3")
list2=list1.clone()
print(list1, "", list2)
# for list1 it prints ->1->2->3->4->None but for list2 it prints ->1->2->3->None
```

I just
Cannot figure out where the mistake as I have been tracing it

UPDATE: I figured that in my text editor I had returned self in the clone function when the list is empty hence it was assigning the object reference of the object that called it to list 2

Comment: indentation issues need to be resolved first.

Comment: Where? I don’t see from my side maybe because I am viewing it from my phone

Comment: `appendEverything(A)` - function is missing self, and seems to have a random k variable.

Comment: there are too much error

Comment: In your tests - where does `ls` come from ? not defined?

Comment: Also, the quotes in your tests are not normal quotes, so this part of the code can't be copy-pasted either.

Comment: I have the made the changes but for test 3 it prints out in reverse

Comment: @ScottC there are no variables in appendEverything(A)  if you are talking about i that’s the iterative variable from the loop

Answer (score 1):

in your clone method change it to:

```
while ptr!=None:
    ls.insert(i,ptr.data)
    ptr=ptr.next
    i+=1
```

Comment: I have made the change buts it’s printing in reverse